# If we know the distribution of the random variable $X$, what is the distribution of $\max\{X,0\}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, maxima-minima

As the title says, we are given a random variable $X$ whose distribution function $F_{X}$ is known. How can we determine the distribution of $Y = \max\{X,0\}$? Here is what I have tried:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y) & = \mathbb{P}(\max\{X,0\} \leq y)\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}((\max\{X,0\} \leq y)\wedge(X\geq 0)) + \mathbb{P}((\max\{X,0\}\leq y)\wedge(X < 0))\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(0\leq X \leq y) + \mathbb{P}(X < 0\leq y)\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(0\leq X \leq y) + \mathbb{P}(X < 0)\\\\
& = F_{X}(y) - F_{X}(0^{-}) + F_{X}(0^{-})\\\\
& = F_{X}(y).
\end{align*}

and then I get stuck as I do not know what to do with the second term from the above expression.

I can see that, if $y < 0$, then $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y) = 0$. But what if $y\geq 0$?

Comment: Split into the cases $y<0$ and $y\ge 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat I have already done that. What is the value of the expression $\mathbb{P}(0\leq y)$ when $y\geq 0$?

Comment: For $y\ge 0$ the distribution functions will be the same. If $y<0$ then $F_Y(y) = 0$.

Comment: I must be missing something very important as I do not know how this relates to $\mathbb{P}(0\leq y)$. According to your reasoning, one should conclude that $\mathbb{P}(0\leq y) = F_{X}(0)$. Is this correct? If so, why?

Comment: I think I have found my mistake. I have edited my answer.

Comment: If $y \ge 0$ then $X(\omega) \le y$ **iff** $Y(\omega) \le y$. So $F_X(y) = F_Y(y)$ in this case. If $y < 0$ then $F_Y(y) = 0$.